# JPQL / JPA query to order entities based on the greatest/maximum of two columns?

Tags: jpa, jpql

I need something similar to this SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM foo f ORDER BY GREATEST(f.bar_date, f.baz_date)
```

As not all RDBMS systems support the `GREATEST` function, ideally I would like the JPA implementation to generate the correct SQL query for the underlying database. The databases that I am targetting are Oracle, SQL Server, and PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JPQL allows the FUNCTION operator to call a database function.

Oracle and Postgres support GREATEST, I don't think SQL Server does, so for it you may be able to write your own function.

You could also use a CASE function with >.

Answer (score 0):

To put this a little more concrete - you could do this in JPQL with the `CASE` statement, which is supported since JPA 2.0. I've omitted the `_date` suffixes for brevity.

```
SELECT * FROM foo f ORDER BY CASE WHEN f.bar > f.baz THEN f.bar ELSE f.baz END
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used CASE function.

Via criteria builder it looks like:

```
CriteriaQuery<?> query = ...
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

query.orderBy(builder.selectCase().when(builder.greaterThan(pathToBarDate, pathToBazDate),pathToBarDate).otherwise(pathToBazDate));
```

In JPQL it should look like

```
ORDER BY
     CASE WHEN (f.bar_date>f.baz_date) THEN f.bar_date
          ELSE f.baz_date
```